# Help identifying low-res kanji (and perhaps words) on a low-res album cover

Tags: translation, kanji, names, writing-identification

Listening to an ancient rip of Escaflowne soundtrack, I wanted to add artist information to one file. I managed to identify some things from context and matching guesses to dictionary entries, but not all, and the scan is low-quality.　So then I got curious and wanted to find the actual kanji and their meanings.

[image: Exerpt from "Escaflowne OST 2" leaflet with song details]
The song in question is nr 17: "If You".
* 作詞: ACEILUX is, I guess, lyricist.
* 作曲 is composer, but I can't identify the second word: [something]曲.
* 菅野よう子 is Yoko Kanno. That was the easy part, with two ひらがな and some anime knowledge.
* The last could mean singer, from context, but I didn't find the actual kanji using jisho.org, and the name is just illegible (to me).

So basically, I'd love it if someone who actually knows kanji could identify them for me, and maybe give a romanized version of the last name.

Comment: Hello!  I'm glad you found the answer too, but please don't edit answers into questions.  If you'd like to post an answer, please do it by answering your own question.  Thank you!

Comment: For Yoko Kanno CDs up until around 2009, check out [this discography](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20100617011606/http://www.members.shaw.ca/ykdb/discography/index.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

作詞{さくし} on its own refers to the act of writing lyrics and not the person. It is being used to credit the lyricist but does not technically have that meaning. Compare it to saying "Lyrics: John Doe" in English.
Next you have 作曲{さっきょく}・編曲{へんきょく}, which is composition and arrangement.
Last is 歌{うた}, and the singer is 山根{やまね}麻衣{まい}, or Mai Yamane.

Comment: Hah, you ninja-d the singer, just figured it out myself :D 
どうもありがとうございます！ I doubt I would've figured out the rest myself.

Comment: 作詞 does not mean "lyricist".

Comment: @TokyoNagoya What does it mean, if not "lyricist"?

Comment: @senshin I think that 作詞 is 歌詞を作ること, and 作詞家 is "lyricist".

Comment: If you want to be technical then yeah it's not lyricist, but in this case, for all intents and purposes, that's what it means.